# Why do batch_normalization produce all-zero output when training = True but produce non-zero output when training = False?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am following the Tensorflow tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate. Here is an example:

```
def model(x, training, scope='model'):
  with v1.variable_scope(scope, reuse=v1.AUTO_REUSE):
    x = v1.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 3, activation=v1.nn.relu,
          kernel_regularizer=lambda x:0.004*tf.reduce_mean(x**2))
    x = v1.layers.max_pooling2d(x, (2, 2), 1)
    x = v1.layers.flatten(x)
    x = v1.layers.dropout(x, 0.1, training=training)
    x = v1.layers.dense(x, 64, activation=v1.nn.relu)
    x = v1.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training)
    x = v1.layers.dense(x, 10)
    return x
train_data = tf.ones(shape=(1, 28, 28, 1))
test_data = tf.ones(shape=(1, 28, 28, 1))
train_out = model(train_data, training=True)
test_out = model(test_data, training=False)
print(train_out)
print(test_out)
```

The train_out where training=True is

```
tf.Tensor([[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

While test_out with training=False is something random non-zero vector

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.379358   -0.55901194  0.48704922  0.11619566  0.23902717  0.01691487
   0.07227738  0.14556988  0.2459927   0.2501198 ]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

I read the document https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization, but I still can't understand why is it? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do batch_normalization produce all-zero output when training =
> True

It's because your batch size = 1 here.

Batch normalization layer normalizes its input by using batch mean and batch standard deviation **for each channel**.

When the batch size is 1 and after flatten, there is only one single value in each channel, so that the batch mean(for that channel) will be the single value itself, thus outputting a zero tensor after the batch normalization layer.

> but produce non-zero output when training = False?

During inference, batch normalization layer normalizes inputs by using moving average of batch mean and SD instead of current batch mean and SD.

The moving mean and SD are initialized as zero and one respectively and updated gradually. Therefore, the moving mean doesn't equal that single value in each channel at the beginning, therefore the layer will not output a zero tensor.

In conclusion: use batch size > 1 and input tensor with random values/realistic data values rather than `tf.ones()` in which all elements are the same.

Comment: But the non-zero output by training=False is randomly varying during each run even I remove the dropout layer, I can't see a random factor in the code?

Comment: If you run model(data,training=False) "consecutively", the output shouldn't be changed. But if there is model(data,training=True) call in between two model(data,training=False) calls, the output can be different because the moving average of batch mean and SD will be updated by the training=True call.

Comment: I find the randomness comes from the conv2d and two dense layers. I set the 3 layers with kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(), then the randomness is eliminated. As your answer, with training=True, the output of the batch_normalization layer turns to zero, while with training=False, the batch_normalization layer maintains a non-zero output. I'd like to understand some of the layers/operations' base property before input realistic data to them : )

Comment: Is there any reason that you want to use those deprecated APIs? Just found that they didn't work as expected by re-initializing variables every time(in the def model function), thus causing the randomness issue you encountered. Those APIs are no longer supported and I suggest you to use the v2 keras api, which will work properly.

Comment: If you are new to tensorflow, please follow this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model . Do not follow that migration guide which could be misleading.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to rewrite this work https://github.com/snowkylin/rnn-handwriting-generation in tf 2.

Comment: And for the code in this question, I think the randomness not comes from the deprecated APIs, but because the conv2d and dense layer have random weight initialization, since I set them with kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer() and the randomness disappears.

Comment: It is correct to do random weight initialization by default "at the first time" model() is called. Then, it is supposed to keep and reuse those initialized weights as you have set the reuse=v1.AUTO_REUSE rather than re-initializing them every time model() is called, causing changing outputs every time.